# Fill in missing numbers in a sequence in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a source xml file, which contains tests and their results, as well as indexes for those tests. The input format looks roughly like this:

**Source XML:**

```
<Test>
  <Name>Test1</Name>
  <Results>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result1</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>0</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result2</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>-1</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result3</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>-1</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result4</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>2</Col>
    </Item>
  </Results>
</Test>
```

I want to have the same structure as before, but every index (be it row or column) that is -1, has to be automatically incremented, starting at 0. There should be no duplicates, so Result2 should not get a 0 for its column, but rather a 1 and Result3 should have a column value of 3. The '-1' are a form of indicating dynamic indexes, which are not defined beforehand, but rather after some other transformations (which will be performed before I want to do the index sequence change).
Sorting will be done later, according to the indexes (the names don't usually have any numbers in them).

I've tried working with position() or keys, but couldn't figure out a way to use them in a way, which would solve my problem at hand. Right now I only have a transformation, which counts upwards, with no regard to any other existing index of the same value.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Results">
  <xsl:for-each select="Item/Col">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Item/Col = -1">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="Item/Col"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Test>
  <Name>Test1</Name>
  <Results>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result1</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>0</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result2</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>1</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result4</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>2</Col>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Result3</Name>
      <Row>0</Row>
      <Col>3</Col>
    </Item>
  </Results>
</Test>
```

The source has no duplicates itself, only multiple '-1' indexes are possible. The output should have no duplicates and also no more -1 for its indexes.

So now the question is, how can I fill up the number sequence, without adding any duplicates to it?

Comment: The question is not clear. Does your source really have duplicate indexes? Please include the desired output, and make sure we understand **why** the output is the way it is.

Comment: Alright, I added the desired output. The -1 indexes are only placeholders and are meant to be replaced by indexes that are 0 or bigger, without the replacements being equal to any already existing index.  I hope this clears my question up.

Comment: I am afraid the logic still escapes me. It seems to you have simply renumbered the cols sequentially, starting from 0? -- If you want to preserve the existing non-negative numbers, how about replacing the negative ones with numbers that are higher than the maximum?